# Orbeon 4.2 Form Builder makes /crud/orbeon/builder/form/form.xhtml request to the custom persistence layer

Tags: orbeon

I'm switching from orbeon `3.9` to `4.2`

I achieved the state when forms from the database are rendered by the form runner, but can't make form builder work. When I try to edit form in a builder. Form Runner makes `/crud/orbeon/builder/form/form.xhtml` GET request to custom persistence instead of using form builder `form.xhtml`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a default property which is set as follows:

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.orbeon.builder.form"
    value="resource"/>
```

This property tells Form Builder to load itself from the built-in resources. You must have a property which overrides that default. Try finding it and changing it.

Comment: Thank you. I did override the "resource" with property oxf.fr.persistence.resource.uri To fix the problem I just needed to rename this property to oxf.fr.persistence.custom.uri and change provider value accordingly.